# Is there a way to update or remove part of a property with cypher in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently working with a database of incident nodes that have a timestamp property. Some of the nodes have a correct timestamp, formatted this way:

```
"02:20:05"
```

Others are incorrectly formatted this way:

```
"T:02:20:05"
```

where the `"T"` was inadvertently captured in the upload. Is there a way in Cypher to do something like this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.Time =~ '(?i)T:.*'
REMOVE n.Time{T:} 
return n.Time
```

So that I can preserve the trailing timestamp data after the `"T:"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE n.Time =~ '(?i)T:.*'
SET n.Time = right(n.Time, length(n.Time)-2)
RETURN n.Time
```